# Why I can't load classes from other assemblies?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

In the `web.config` of my MVC project, I have this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MembershipRepository" value="Repo.MembershipRepository"/>
</appSettings>
```

I have a code like this:

```
var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings; 
string membershipRepositoryClassName = appSettings["MembershipRepository"];
Type membershipRepositoryType = Type.GetType(membershipRepositoryClassName);
IMembershipRepository repository = (IMembershipRepository)Activator.CreateInstance(membershipRepositoryType);
```

Suppose, the web application containing the `web.config` is in assembly `Web`.
The code segment I gave is in assembly `Lib`.
The class `MembershipRepository` is in assembly `Repo`.
`Web` has reference to both `Lib` and `Repo`.
`Lib` does not have reference to any other assemblies (Its liekly to be referenced as dll).
`Repo` may or may not have reference to `Lib`.

I get the `membershipRepositoryType` to be `null`. I understand that perhaps I need to specify the assembly in which `MembershipRepository` is. One way is to specify the assembly name in configuration (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688449/887149)). But I think there should be some other ways. Otherwise how the other classes are loaded geting only the class name from the config file?
For instance, `MembershipProvider` class is loaded just fine from other assemblies.

How can I do the same. Or if I can't, why I can't?

Comment: Troubleshooting tip: Pass `true` to `Type.GetType`—`Type.GetType(membershipRepositoryClassName, true)`—so that you get a detailed exception describing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MSDN Library documentation for [`Type.GetType(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx):

> *typeName:* The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx). If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

That last sentence explains why it sometimes works when you specify only the class name: If the executing code is in `Repo`, then you can get away with just specifying `MembershipProvider`. But I recommend that for clarity (and performance too), you avoid this behavior and always specify the assembly name. Alternately, if you already have a reference to the `Assembly` that contains your type, then you can call [`Assembly.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/etfka5f1) instead.

Nevertheless, if you truly have a scenario where you don't know which assembly contains your type, then you can search all loaded assemblies in the current AppDomain and try calling `Assembly.GetType` on each one:

```
Type type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Select(assembly => assembly.GetType(typeName))
    .First(t => t != null);
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything. I should specify the assembly in the configuration. Getting the _most probable_ type from all assemblies is not a good idea of course. I was just trying to realize **Why I need to specify the assembly when some one else does not need**. Now I realize that some of my previous configurations worked just luckily!!

Comment: Reexamining the configurations, it looks like I need not specify assembly if the assembly is referenced in the current project. Is it so?

Comment: As far as I know, no, that isn't the case. For example, even though your project probably references System.dll, `Type.GetType("System.Uri")` will always return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is something like this:

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
    .SelectMany( s => s.GetTypes() )
    .Where( p => p.Name == membershipRepositoryClassName );
```

That is actually going to return a list, because a type with the same name may be declared in more than one assembly. If you are sure there is only one type, you can add `.FirstOrDefault()` or `.Single()` to the end of the chain. Use `.FirstOrDefault()` if you aren't sure if the type exists and want it to return null if it doesn't. Use `.Single()` if you are sure the type should exist is and want it to throw an exception if they type isn't found.